# Add NBTTagList entry to ItemStack in onBlockActivated

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I have an item that should add the coordinates of a specific block when right-clicking the block with it. The coordinates are stored in a NBTTagList.

The problem is that the changes to the ItemStack will not be saved. It is not saved in the level.dat, which hold the Player's items in single player. Also the addInformation method which uses the data will not get anything.

**The sources:**

The onBlockActivate method of the target block class:

```
if (player.getCurrentEquippedItem() != null &&
            player.getCurrentEquippedItem().getItem() == ModItems.teleportationTablet) {
        if (world.isRemote) {
            ItemStack teletab = player.getCurrentEquippedItem().copy();

            if (teletab.stackTagCompound == null)
                teletab.stackTagCompound = new NBTTagCompound();


            NBTTagList targets = teletab.stackTagCompound.getTagList("targets", 10);

            NBTTagCompound location = new NBTTagCompound();

            location.setInteger("x", x);
            location.setInteger("y", y);
            location.setInteger("z", z);
            location.setInteger("dim", world.provider.dimensionId);

            targets.appendTag(location);

            teletab.stackTagCompound.setTag("targets", targets);

            player.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("Your teleportation tablet is now linked!"));
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Methods from the item class:

```
@Override
public void addInformation(ItemStack teletab, EntityPlayer player, List list, boolean par4) {
    NBTTagCompound tag = teletab.getTagCompound();

    if (tag != null) {
        NBTTagList targets = tag.getTagList("targets", 10);

        if (targets.tagCount() != 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < targets.tagCount(); i++) {
                NBTTagCompound target = targets.getCompoundTagAt(i);
                list.add(String.format("Linked with target at X=%d, Y=%d, Z=%d, Dim=%d", target.getInteger("x"),  target.getInteger("y"),  target.getInteger("z"),  target.getInteger("dim")));
            }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreated(ItemStack stack, World world, EntityPlayer player) {
    stack.setTagCompound(new NBTTagCompound());
    stack.stackTagCompound.setTag("targets", new NBTTagList());
}
```

Comment: You're writing your tag to the client side, which means the server doesn't even know it exists.  Either write it on the server and send a packet to the client, or vice versa.  `world.isRemote` means client side, follow the answer below, but also packet syncing.

Answer (score 1):

Try change

```
if (world.isRemote) {
```

to

```
if (!world.isRemote) {
```

**Edit #1:**
The `isRemote` flag can be confusing. Its used to show whether the reference to the world is *remote*. For a *client*, a remote world (where `isRemote == true`) shows that the world actually lies on the server so no changes should be made. This can be used (like it commonly is) to show whether the *currently running code* is server side or client side.

That means that the world should only be altered when `isRemote == false`, meaning that the *currently running code* has access to directly change things.

Since you run code that changes stuff (a NBT tag of an ItemStack to be exact) where `isRemote == true` a problem occurs, since the currently running code is not able to apply those changes, as the actual world object is on the server.

Comment: I think this will not work because the server saves NBT data in the world.

Comment: @Kim This is not true.